# Connecting Strapi and Next.JS but getting an error

Tags: javascript, next.js, strapi, bootstrap-image-gallery

Two terminals are opened, one for Strapi and one for Next.JS.
I have set up the configuration in Strapi.
I want to receive the API in Next.JS and display it on the screen, but it does not show up. Then I get an error screen.
I tested with Postman and confirmed that Get and Post can be done.

I get this error in my browser.

```
    Server Error
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:1337

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Call Stack
<unknown> (Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
: (1:1337)
TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete]
node:net (1237:16)
```

```
ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
wait  - compiling...
event - compiled client and server successfully in 393 ms (125 modules)
wait  - compiling / (client and server)...
wait  - compiling...
event - compiled client and server successfully in 128 ms (144 modules)
wait  - compiling /_error (client and server)...
wait  - compiling...
event - compiled client and server successfully in 56 ms (145 modules)
error - Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:1337
```

index.js

```
import Head from "next/head";
import Image from "next/image";
import styles from "../styles/Home.module.css";
import axios from "axios";

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const foodsData = await (
    await axios.get("http://localhost:1337/api/foods")
  ).data.data;

  console.log(foodsData);

  return {
    props: {
      foods: foodsData,
    },
  };
}

export default function Home({ foods }) {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <main className={styles.main}>
        <h1 className={styles.title}>Welcome to My Shopping</h1>
        <div className={styles.grid}>
          {foods.map((food, index) => (
            <>
              <a
                href="https://nextjs.org/docs"
                className={styles.card}
                key={index}
              >
                <h2>{food.attributes.title}</h2>
                <p>{food.attributes.description}</p>
                <div>価格：{food.attributes.price}</div>
              </a>
            </>
          ))}
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

How can this be corrected?
help me plese.

Comment: It looks like an issue with the strapi server. Taking next.js out of the equation, are you able to get data by doing `curl http://localhost:1337/api/foods` in the terminal (or making the request with a tool like postman)

Comment: We have confirmed that Postman can be used to receive and add json data to STRAPI.

Comment: What Node.js version are you on? Have you tried replacing `localhost:1337` with `127.0.0.1:1337`?

Comment: Can you add code / instructions for how you are starting the Strapi server? (I am unable to re-produce this)

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue. Change http://localhost:3000 to http://127.0.0.1:1337

Comment: oh wow, thank you!! But why is this configured so it doesn't recognise local host?